# Как принять пакет на сервере?

Tags: php, http

С помощью VBS отправляется пакет на заданный URL:

```
Set oHTTP = CreateObject("winhttp.winhttprequest.5.1")
sSource = "http://www.site.ru/gate.php?id=" & strSourceFile & ""
oHTTP.open "GET", sSource, False
oHTTP.send
```

Мне нужен простейший пример PHP скрипта, чтобы можно было принять этот пакет. Надеюсь, не нужно будет писать демон какой-то, ибо я с ними никогда не работал. Но нужно как-то запустить скрипт, чтобы он работал постоянно и принимал пакеты.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GET** подразумевает открытие ссылки (как вы в браузере). Поэтому никаких демонов вам не нужно.

Файл **gate.php** должен обрабатывать глобальный массив **$_GET[]**

В вашем случае **$_GET['id']**

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$some = $_GET['some']; 
//somecode
?>
```